# ¿Que es esta funcion en JavaScript? delete

Tags: javascript

Estuve viendo algo de código javascript y me tope con una función que en una parte realiza algo que no entiendo, **estuve buscando por internet pero no me aparece lo que estoy tratando de buscar.**

```
function iniciarSesion(correo,password)
{
    let enviar = true;
    var formData = {}; // Objeo que guarda los inputs
    var elementos = $("#formRegistro input");
    let el;

    for(let i = 0; i < elementos.length; i++){
        el = $(elementos[i]); // Elementos del form
        formData[el.attr("name")] = el.val();
    }

    if( formData["correo"] === "" ) delete formData["correo"];
    if( formData["password"] === "" ) delete formData["password"];
}


**Estas lineas son las que no entiendo**

if( formData["correo"] === "" ) delete formData["correo"];

if( formData["password"] === "" ) delete formData["password"];
```

Comment: Borra una propiedad de un objeto: [Objetos y sus propiedades](http://w3.unpocodetodo.info/jsblog/objetos-propiedades.php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

eso es para borrar esas propiedades del vector de formData
si se fija primero el recorre los inputs del registro y los almacena en el vector formData

despues hace una validacion que si formData["correo"] esta vacio entonces quite formData["correo"] y hace lo mismo con password

por ejemplo si tengo este vector

```
 var persona= {
      nombre:"Pedro",
      edad: 32
    };
```

y muestro una alerta con la edad

```
 alert(persona.edad)
```

me va a aparecer "32" pero si despues le hago un `delete` a persona.edad y hago otra vez esa alerta el mensaje que va a salir es "`undefined`" porque ya esa propiedad no existe